# Reconstructing a XORed UTF-8 encoded text in javascript, client side, no Node

Tags: javascript, python, encoding, utf-8, client-side

I am driving nuts trying to achieve this in JavaScript. 
First I will describe the scenario, and then I'll put my code, Python version, which I can't seem to translate into JavaScript.

I have a web page running on a server. I have no access to it whatsoever, so the only way I have to achieve basic functionality is using JavaScript.
The web page is used to compare information. The information is stored in CSV format, which I use to create HTML tables on the fly by using AJAX calls. For the sake of not having that information quickly available to users, enabling them to print the source code and 'stealing it', I came across a range of solutions, like encoding in Base64 (I know this is considered 'security by obscurity' and it's a bad practice, but I have no other choice here).

Base64 it's very easy to use in this case, but I lose all the special characters from UTF-8 (like á é í ó ú ñ etc), which are part of my language (Spanish).

So here comes the preferred solution, which works like a charm in Python: using bitwise XOR. What could I achieve using this method:

- If someone figures out the url of the CSV file, it wouldn't be so easy to read the text without basic programming knowledge to de-encode it.
- I can easily program the source database to export the data and then run the XORing fuction, upload those files to the server and then having them de-encoded on the fly too.

Is in that last step where I can not achieve what I want.

Here is my Python script:
To encode:

```
b = bytearray(open('file.csv', 'rb').read())

for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] ^= 0x71

open('file.out', 'wb').write(b)
```

To decode:

```
b = bytearray(open('file.out', 'rb').read())
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] ^= 0x71
```

I need to achieve that small decoding function in JS.
Thank you all in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Base64

It isn't true that base64 makes you lose non-ASCII characters like *ñ* or *á*. Why should it? Base64 can encode any binary data, and encoded text is nothing else than binary data.

So encoding involves two steps:
A *text encoding* (such as UTF-8) converts your text to bytes, and the base64 encoding turns that into an ASCII string.
Decoding works the same, but backwards (reverse order of the two corresponding decoding functions).

This is how text encoding for UTF-8 works in JavaScript:

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

I got this from [here](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.ch/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html). Please note that I'm not a JS crack at all, and there might be more convenient methods now that I couldn't find.

Let's try this:

```
s = 'Se bañó todo el día.';
b = encode_utf8(s);  # text encoding
a = btoa(b);         # base64 encoding
console.log(a);      # prints U2UgYmHDscOzIHRvZG8gZWwgZMOtYS4=

d = decode_utf8(atob(a));  # decode base64, then UTF-8
console.log(d);      # prints Se bañó todo el día.
```

No character lost here.

#### XOR method

If you still want to do the XOR thing, you can decode as follows:

- convert the UTF8-encoded string to an array of code points with `Array.from()`
- XOR-decode with the `^` operator (or `^=` assignment)
- convert the result to a string with `String.fromCodePoint()`
- decode the string with `decode_utf8()`

I'm not providing code for this, though.
Especially the third step might be a bit cumbersome, and I'm not sure if it's worth the pain.
After all, your users can just inspect the JS code to find out how the data are "encrypted", be it base64 or the XOR method.

#### Note

If you come from a Python background, be aware that there is no distinction like Python's `str` and `bytes` type. Both input and output of the `{en,de}code_utf8()` functions are always strings, same type. When you encode a string, you just get back another string where every codepoint is below 256, and it might be longer than the input string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanation. I will edit my original post, adding my experience with Base64 and character encoding (differences between Python and Javascript). Thanks again!